# setCallback in contoroller does NOT work

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

There are two main functions of the component I want to make,
1.Display the component if there is a target record,
2.Display the items of the target record on the component.

However, it will not work because $ A.enqueueAction (action) will be executed without waiting for setCallback.
Please tell me how to deal with it.

Thank you.

alertController.apxc

```
public with sharing class AlertController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Chip__c> getChipList() {
        List<Chip__c> chipList =[Select Name, format(LastDate__c) From Chip__c where LastDate__c < LAST_WEEK];          
        return chipList;   
    }

    /**
*判定する 
*/
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean getJudgeLastDate(){
        Boolean isExist = false;

        List<Chip__c> result = getChipList();

        if(result.size()>0){
            isExist = true;
        }
        return isExist;
    }
}
```

alertChip.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="AlertController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isVisible" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this }" action="{!c.sampleAction}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>

    <!--isVisibleがtrueのとき表示-->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isVisible}">
        <lightning:card iconName="action:announcement" title="アラート">
            <lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }" columns="{! v.mycolumns }" keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
        </lightning:card>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

alertChip.js

```
({

    sampleAction : function(component,event,helper){
        component.set("v.Columns", [
            {label:"シリアル", fieldName:"Name", type:"text"},
            {label:"最終日", 
             fieldName:"LastDate__c",
             type:"date"}
        ]);

        var action = component.get("c.getChipList");        
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {

            component.set("v.mydata",response.getReturnValue());
            var state = response.getState();

            if (state === "SUCCESS") 
            {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());

                //--------second controller Starts--------------               
                var action_2 = component.get("c.getJudgeLastDate");

                action_2.setCallback(this, function(data) {
                    var state2 = data.getState();

                    //trueのとき
                    if(action_2){
                        //表示する
                        action_2.setCallback(this, function(data) {
                            component.set("v.isVisible",true);
                            alert('true');
                        });
                    }    
                });



                //action_2について完了
                alert("enqueueAction(action_2)");
                $A.enqueueAction(action_2);
            }
        });

        //actionについて完了
        alert("enqueueAction(action)");
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } 
})
```

Comment: You can use javascript promise or after getting success message call another helper method you are doing completely wrong in js side

Comment: You have action_2 and action2, is that a typo?

Comment: It was a copy mistake. sorry！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this pattern:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm

Create and split your server calls as promises on the helper, then chain them on your js controller with .then().then() and if you will only one .catch() at the end like explained on docs.

sample js controller:

```
mainMethod : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getContactPromise1(component)
    .then(
         $A.getCallback(function(result) {
            return helper.getContactPromise2(component)
         })
    )
    .then(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            alert("alert after 2nd call")
        })
    ).catch(function(error) {
         $A.reportError("Oops", error);
    })
}
```

sample js helper:

```
getContactPromise1: function(component) {
    return new Promise($A.getCallback(function(resolve, reject) {
        var action = component.get("c.getContact")
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("1st call");
                resolve("Resolved");
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                reject("Rejected");
                console.log('oops');
            }
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }));
},
getContactPromise2: function(component) {
    return new Promise($A.getCallback(function(resolve, reject) {
        var action = component.get("c.getContact")
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("2nd call");
                resolve("Resolved");
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                reject("Rejected");
                console.log('oops');
            }
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }));
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: I did it!
Thank you! 
ありがとうございました！